# Need help Visual Basic IsDate(), European date (dd/mm/yyyy) format function

Tags: vb.net, date, datetime, vb.net-2010

I'm brand new to Visual Basic and I need some help with a program I'm working on.

I have 3 seperate textboxes for Day, Month and Year and none accept any other character then number. 
Now I want to make a code, so that program checks current date everytime and reminds you if you enter a date that has already expired, for example if you enter D: 11   M: 11   Y: 2012.

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Any particular reason you'd prefer to have the input as 3 `Textbox`es, rather than a `DatePicker`? (That most people are used to, that will restrict input to valid dates for you, that gives you a `DateTime` to work with straight away)?

Comment: Also, if this is for some kind of validation message, it would be useful to know what UI system you're working with - WinForms, WPF, Silverlight, ASP.Net?

Comment: Is this a recent version of VB, or VB6?

Comment: Well I'm working on a simple app that'd ease my work at work and 3 text boxes input seems the fastest and much more organised as I'd like to copy/paste dates from Excel. (if there's an easier way with only one textbox then I think it's even better)

Comment: Jon: I'm using VB 2010 that I got free on Microsoft website, but I did install it about a week ago so it has to be recent one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Air code.

```
Dim theYear As Integer, theMonth As Integer, theDay As Integer 
' get text from textboxes and convert to numbers 
If Not Int32.TryParse(txtYear.Text, theYear) Then 
  MsgBox "Please enter a valid year!"
  Exit Sub
End If
If Not Int32.TryParse(txtMonth.Text, theMonth) Then 
  MsgBox "Please enter a valid month!"
  Exit Sub
End If
If Not Int32.TryParse(txtDay.Text, theDay) Then 
  MsgBox "Please enter a valid day!"
  Exit Sub
End If  
' combine numbers into a Date 
Dim theDate As Date = Nothing 
Try
  theDate As New Date(theYear, theMonth, theDay) 
Catch e As Exception 
   'year is less than 1 or greater than 9999. 
  '-or- 
  'month is less than 1 or greater than 12. 
  '-or- 
  'day is less than 1 or greater than the number of days in month. 
  MsgBox "Please enter a valid date!"
  Exit Sub
End Try 
 ' check whether date is in the past 
Dim nowDate As Date = DateTime.Now
If DateTime.Compare(theDate, nowDate) < 0 Then
  MsgBox "That date has expired" 
End If
```

Documentation links:

- [Date constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcfzdy4x%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)
- [DateTime.Now](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx)
- [DateTime.Compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your answer MarkJ allthough I have couple of questions. First, why is there YYYY/MM/DD and not the other way around?

Secondly, can I link the following variables as:

`theYear = InputYear.text
theMonth = InputMonth.text
theDay = InputDay.text`

...so the text input from boxes can be put into Int.

Comment: I get two errors from that code: 

- 'Catch (e As Exception) -> End of statement required'

- 'If DateTime.Compare(theDate, nowDate) < 0 Then -> 
Error 2 'theDate' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.'

Allthough it clearly is declared.

Comment: See edits. "air code" means I haven't compiled it or run it. (i just typed it on my phone in a spare moment when I didn't happen to have access to a PC) Note that I am taking the year, month & day values from textboxes.

Comment: Thanks solved the problem right after. I deleted the "Catch e As Exception" part (don't know what it does either) and it works fine. Allthough it set today's date as expired so I put +1 to "txtDay.Text". Thanks for your help, case closed. :)

Comment: @Alex Can I offer a friendly word of advice with no offence meant!! It's always a good idea to be sure you understand code before you use it, otherwise it might not be doing what you need. Anyway, the exception handling is in case the user enters bogus dates, like day=30 and month = 2.

Comment: BTW if the answer solved your problem you can "accept" it by clicking on the transparent tick next to the answer.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks. Yeah I thought it's that as you wrote comments below the function, but I already had a different code doing that job so there's nothing missing. I tested it with all possible bugs and it works fine.